# Why can't I inject my service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following new service:

```
var SignatureService = function ($scope) {

    this.announce = function () {
        alert($scope.specificName);
    }
};
SignatureService.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

This is declared for the app as follows:

```
MyAngularApp.service('SignatureService', SignatureService);
```

Several other services are added to the app in exactly the same way, and they all seem to work OK. I then have a controller declared and defined as follows:

```
MyAngularApp.controller('MyController', MyController);
...
var MyController = function ($scope, Service1, Service2, $location, $modal, SignatureService) {
...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Service1', 'Service2', '$location', '$modal', 'SignatureService'];
```

I am simply using the slightly unconvcentionaly manner of defining the servivce and injecting it that is standard in the app I am working on, as this works for all existing services, and I would prefer to simply slot mine in as per standard.

When the controller loads, I get an `[$injector:unpr]` in the browser console, with the error info:

```
$injector/unpr?p0=$scopeProvider <- $scope <- SignatureService
```

Comment: A service can't have a `$scope`. The `$scope` always lives in a controller or directive context. You can use the `$rootScope` though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't inject `$scope` into your custom service. It just doesn't make sense since `SignatureService` can be injected anywhere including other services and other controlles. What `$scope` is supposed to be if you say inject it into two nested controllers, which one should be injected?

Scope object (`$scope`) is always associated with some DOM node, it is attached to it. That's why you see `$scope` in controllers and directives. And this is the reason why you can't have it in service: services are not related to specific DOM elements. Of course you can inject `$rootScope` but this is unlikely what you need in your question.

Summary: `$scope` is created from the `$rootScope` and injected in necessary controllers, but you can't injected it into custom service.

**UPD.** Based on comments you want to use service to define reusable controller methods. In this case I would go with what I call mixin approach. Define methods in the service and mix them in the necessary controllers.

```
app.service('controllerMixin', function() {
    this.getName = function() {
        alert(this.name);
    };
});
```

and then extend controller scope with `angular.extend`:

```
app.controller('OneController', function($scope, controllerMixin) {
    angular.extend($scope, controllerMixin);
    // define controller specific methods
});

app.controller('TwoController', function($scope, controllerMixin) {
    angular.extend($scope, controllerMixin);
    // define controller specific methods
});
```

This is pretty effective, because `controllerMixin` doesn't have any notion of `$scope` whatsoever, when mixed into controller you refer to the scope with `this`. Also service doesn't change if you prefer to use controllerAs syntax, you would just extend `this`:

```
angular.extend(this, controllerMixin);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ePhSF8UttR4IgeUjLRSt?p=info

Comment: OK, thanks, but the reason trying to access `$scope` in the service is I'm trying to create a central function that can be called to alter a model on one of several scopes. Any suggestion how I could do that?

Comment: Service should not change scope. Services modify/load data, etc. You should inject service into necessary controller and then use it's methods.

Comment: So in the controller, I pass `$scope` to the service method? My problem here is I'm trying to share one method between many controllers, and I thought a service would be the way to go.

Comment: Pass scope as a parameter to that "central function".

Comment: @ProfK Check updated answer with simple and effective mixix solution.